# Is it possible to create 3d games with good performance in java?

Tags: java, performance

Recently i use Javafx 8 for creating small 2D games , but i think it can't manage memory and other things very well .I see Jmonkey [jmonkeyengine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) as a game engine for Java and i see some videos of their project in YouTube. Now i want to know it is possible to create a good game with good performance and graphic with Jmonkey or other game engines writtent in java? Is it possible to deal with GPU buffers in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is a bit slower then c++ however this effect is less then people tend to think. There are several points on which it matters:

1 Calls towards openGL will have to take another extra step this means that if you make many calls towards openGL you pay a small penalty (not that large but it's there).

2 You don't control the garbage collector that means that you will sometimes seem to miss one frame, this isn't that bad but can screw up your game in a multiplayer environment especially when using a lock-step approach for resolving concurancy issues (for example in a rts).

3 You cannot do a clear memory and then rewrhite step approach for example in c++ you might decide to first clear the old map then write a new one in the same memory, if you are using almost all memory this will cause problems, note that you can almost always navitage around this by instead of "destroy and recreate" you can often just rewrite the object instead.

4 Often c++ programers are better used towards performance based programming, well focus on performance and this won't be a problem.

If you want to know about fps take a look at for example minecraft and you will see you can get some reasonble performance in java (note minecraft could be optimised a lot more).

Comment: Your're right but do we have a game with a very well performance in java ?

Comment: The garbage collector shouldn't make a difference in a lockstep game, it would simply require waiting a bit longer for all the inputs sometimes but it doesn't mess up the determinism of the simulation.

Comment: another question is it good to switch to Jmoneky for creating a strategic game like warcraft or age of empire ?(for both performance and speed)

Comment: You can do this if you don't plan on multiplayer using the lock step approach as described here http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131503/1500_archers_on_a_288_network_.php

Comment: so as i see , can we say Java and engines written in java is not good for multiplayer games ?

Comment: They work poorly for certain implementations of multilayer. If you need every frame to be made in a constant and predictable speed then java will work poorly(you are actually setting up race conditions) where C++ gives you some extra control over how memory is handled and thus prevent untimely handling of these issues. If you design ever states"each frame must be handled in less then x ms" then java might not work, note that java can work in "on average each frame must work in x ms" just not "no frame can take longer then x ms"

Answer (score 1):

Let me get this straight: render performance is in (almost) no way related to the programming language, but to the **graphics API used** (Ex: OpenGL, DirectX, software, etc.) The programming language used is only an interface to these APIs and will not affect graphics performance.

What the language will have an impact on is the arithmetics. If you want to do a lot of calculation, then you will need to chose a fast language like C or C++. If you only need to do graphics, then any language will do (hell, even Brainfuck for what I care.)

Comment: Java needs to make a call to a little C program for each call to openGL slowing it down a little and you have less control over memory. In my experience java is only around 10% slower when doing calculations as long as you program them equally well.

Comment: Yes, Java is a little slower when doing calculations, but for graphics rendering, the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: @Thisjser And I totally agree with you for the control over memory. Java gives you less, but the JVM and GC handles it decently if you do not create too much garbage...

Comment: Yes but this means you cannot do a few clever tricks with either holding off memory deletion (for performance) or by clearing memory and directly reclaiming it. For graphics you really are making an extra function call (I did a test where I asked my computer to draw various number of (green) triangles and fps was around 10 to 5% slower (10 with just a few triangles and 5 as we moved towards the 100 000 triangles).

Comment: @Thijser The bottleneck in your example is the CPU. Your graphics card will not render more triangles just because you use C over Java. The problem is that the thread cannot pass as much information to the graphics card. And yes, 5% is irrelevant. It also changes from one system (or library) to another. I did a test myself last week comparing C and Java (SDL vs LWJGL) and I got a +50% graphics performance from Java over C (don't ask me how, I don't even know myself).